# Pass Dispatch to onClick Event Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm digging into my first react/redux application and I've been having quite a bit of trouble mapping my dispatch actions to onClick events in my components.

I've tried a couple of variations of trying to bind the onClick Event to the dispatch, but I always end up with either :

`ReferenceError: onMovieClick is not defined`

or alternatively when I do end up binding a function correctly I'll get an error related to `dispatch is not defined`.

**My Goal**
I'm trying to implement a filter(delete) from store function

**actions/movieActions.js**

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes'

export const createMovie = (movie) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.CREATE_MOVIE,
    movie
  }
};

export const deleteMovie = (id) => {
  console.log('action triggered. movie index:' + id)
  return {
    type: actionTypes.DELETE_MOVIE,
    id
  }
}
```

**reducers/movieReducers.js**

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'CREATE_MOVIE':
      return [
        ...state,
        Object.assign({}, action.movie)
      ];
    case 'DELETE_MOVIE':
      return [
        state.filter(({ id }) => id  !== action.id)
      ]
    default:
          return state;
  }
};
```

**components/MovieList.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-slick'
import { dispatch, connect } from 'react-redux'
import {Icon} from 'react-fa'
import { deleteMovie } from '../../actions/movieActions'

import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css'
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css'
import './MovieList.scss'

class MovieList extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super (props)
  }

  handleClick(id) {
    dispatch(deleteMovie(id))
  }

  onMovieClick(id){
   dispatch.deleteMovie(id)
  }

  render () {
    // Settings for slick-carousel
    let settings = {
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500
    }

    return (
      <div className='col-lg-12'>
        {this.props.movies.map((b, i) =>
          <div key={i} className="col-lg-2">
            <Slider {...settings}>
              {b.images.map((b, z) =>
                <div className="img-wrapper">
                  <Icon name="trash" className="trash-icon" onClick={() =>
                    console.log(this.props.movies[i].id),
                    onMovieClick(this.props.movies[i].id)
                  }/>
                  <img className="img-responsive" key={z} src={b.base64}></img>
                </div>
              )}
            </Slider>
            <div className="text-left info">
              <h2>{b.title}</h2>
              <p>{b.genre}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// map state from store to props

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    movies: state.movies
  }
};

// Map actions to props
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onMovieClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(deleteMovie(id))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MovieList)
```

Would love some advice if anyone has a moment.

Comment: You have duplicate definition of `onMovieClick`, one in props and one in the method of MovieList

Comment: FYI I dont believe this will work if you "Open in new tab"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are passing onMovieClick through connect, you can actually invoke it from the MovieList component props. First, I would remove the `onMovieClick` method definition in your MovieList component and then use `this.props.onMovieClick` in the onclick handler of `Icon` like so:

```js
<Icon name="trash" className="trash-icon" onClick={() =>
  console.log(this.props.movies[i].id),
  this.props.onMovieClick(this.props.movies[i].id)
}/>
```